# Filtering input files using globStatus in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I have a lot of input files and I want to process selected ones based on the date that has been appended in the end. I am now confused on where do I use the globStatus method to filter out the files.

I have a custom RecordReader class and I was trying to use globStatus in its next method but it didn't work out.

```
public boolean next(Text key, Text value) throws IOException {
    Path filePath = fileSplit.getPath();

    if (!processed) {
        key.set(filePath.getName());

        byte[] contents = new byte[(int) fileSplit.getLength()];
        value.clear();
        FileSystem fs = filePath.getFileSystem(conf);
        fs.globStatus(new Path("/*" + date));
        FSDataInputStream in = null;

        try {
            in = fs.open(filePath);
            IOUtils.readFully(in, contents, 0, contents.length);
            value.set(contents, 0, contents.length);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeStream(in);
        }
        processed = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I know it returns a FileStatus array, but how do I use it to filter the files. Can someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `globStatus` method takes 2 complimentary arguments which allow you to filter your files. The first one is the glob pattern, but sometimes glob patterns are not powerful enough to filter specific files, in which case you can define a `PathFilter`.

Regarding the glob pattern, the following are supported:

```
Glob   | Matches
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*      | Matches zero or more characters
?      | Matches a single character
[ab]   | Matches a single character in the set {a, b}
[^ab]  | Matches a single character not in the set {a, b}
[a-b]  | Matches a single character in the range [a, b] where a is lexicographically less than or equal to b
[^a-b] | Matches a single character not in the range [a, b] where a is lexicographically less than or equal to b
{a,b}  | Matches either expression a or b
\c     | Matches character c when it is a metacharacter
```

`PathFilter` is simply an interface like this:

```
public interface PathFilter {
    boolean accept(Path path);
}
```

So you can implement this interface and implement the `accept` method where you can put your logic to filter files.

An example taken from [Tom White's excellent book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449389732) which allows you to define a `PathFilter` to filter files that match a certain regular expression:

```
public class RegexExcludePathFilter implements PathFilter {
    private final String regex;

    public RegexExcludePathFilter(String regex) {
        this.regex = regex;
    }

    public boolean accept(Path path) {
        return !path.toString().matches(regex);
    }
}
```

You can directly filter your input with a `PathFilter` implementation by calling `FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter(JobConf, RegexExcludePathFilter.class)` when initializing your job.

**EDIT**: Since you have to pass the class in `setInputPathFilter`, you can't directly pass arguments, but you should be able to do something similar by playing with the `Configuration`. If you make your `RegexExcludePathFilter` also extend from `Configured`, you can get back a `Configuration` object which you will have initialized before with the desired values, so you can get back these values inside your filter and process them in the `accept`.

For example if you initialize like this:

```
conf.set("date", "2013-01-15");
```

Then you can define your filter like this:

```
public class RegexIncludePathFilter extends Configured implements PathFilter {
    private String date;
    private FileSystem fs;

    public boolean accept(Path path) {
        try {
            if (fs.isDirectory(path)) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        return path.toString().endsWith(date);
    }

    public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
        if (null != conf) {
            this.date = conf.get("date");
            try {
                this.fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**: There were a few issues with the original code, please see the updated class. You also need to remove the constructor since it's not used anymore, and check if that's a directory in which case you should return true so the content of the directory can be filtered too.

Comment: Well, I referred the same. I read these pages and my question is where in the code do I use it? Do I use it in the record reader?

Comment: @Expressions_Galore You can call `FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter(JobConf, PathFilter)` which should allow you to filter your input, you don't really need a recordreader just for that.

Comment: I have a record reader for a different purpose. But when I created a class implementing the PathFilter interface, I got the following message while using the FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter(JobConf, PathFilter) method.
The method setInputPathFilter(JobConf, Class<? extends PathFilter>) in the type FileInputFormat is not applicable for the arguments (JobConf, RegexIncludePathFilter)
Here RegexIncludePathFilter implements PathFilter.

Comment: Try with `FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter(JobConf, RegexIncludePathFilter.class);` instead.

Comment: But then how would I pass it the regex to look for?

Comment: You can define the regex as a constant in your `RegexExcludePathFilter` class so you don't need to pass anything to the constructor, that should do the trick.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22735/discussion-between-expressions-galore-and-charles-menguy)

Comment: Well I tried what you said. I changed your RegexIncludePathFilter class a little bit though.
I dropped the date variable,
set the value of regex in setConf to "^.*" + conf.get("date") + "$"
and changed the argument to regex in the matches() method. But then I received this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.myorg.custom.RegexIncludePathFilter.<init>()

Comment: So I tried another implementation. I initialized a static variable, date, in my main class and then used the value of that variable in the RegexIncludePathFilter class, but it kept processing all the files.

Comment: @Expressions_Galore I got it working, please see updated answer above, tested and works fine for me and only gets files that end with the specified date.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reading this, can I say "please don't do anything more complex in the filters than validating the paths". Specifically: don't do checks for the files being a directory, getting their sizes, etc. Wait until the list/glob operation has returned and then do a filtering there, using the information now in the populated `FileStatus` entries.

Why? All those calls to `getFileStatus()`, directly or via `isDirectory()` are doing needless calls to the filesystem, calls which add needless namenode load on an HDFS cluster. More critically, against S3 and other object stores, each operation is potentially making multiple HTTPS requests —and those really do take measurable time. Even better, S3 will throttle you if it thinks you are making too many requests across your entire cluster of machines. You don't want that.

Wit until after the call —the file status entries you get back are those from the object store's list commands, which usually return thousands of file entries per HTTPS request, and so are way more efficient.

For further details, inspect the source of `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem`.