# hadoop pathFilter failed to filter the given path

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using hadoop 0.20.2 version, I have a map-reduce program that finds max temperature from weather record.My problem here is i have a set of files in the input path and i want to filter out only required files for the mapper. Here in my case , data for the mapper include file name start with sample1.txt ,sample2.txt and so on(the same path having some other files also). How can i input only the files that starts with sample*. I have used the following path filter.

Can any one please help me out?

```
public static class filter implements PathFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return path.toString().contains("sample");
    }

}
```

Driver code consists:

```
     FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter(job, filter.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly use glob, i.e

```
Path inputpath = new Path(args[0] + "/" + "sample" + "*")
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputpath);
```

this is just an alternate of doing what you want.

Comment: it works but small change needed:                                  Path inputpath = new Path(args[0] + "/" + "sample" + "*");
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputpath);  and thank u..

Answer (score -1):

```
public class RegexExcludePathFilter implements PathFilter {
private final String regex;

public RegexExcludePathFilter(String regex) {
    this.regex = regex;
}

public boolean accept(Path path) {
    return !path.toString().matches(regex);
}
}
```

for more click
[here](http://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/hadoop-filter-input-files-used-for-mapreduce/) and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332330/filtering-input-files-using-globstatus-in-mapreduce)

Comment: @Eran i edited my answer or i dont know that link is invalid.... but most of time link is provided by many...

Comment: Thanks! That's better, but it would be even better if you explain how this code answers the question. (BTW, I didn't down vote your answer)